# Как задать размер объекта в координатах?

Tags: unity3d

Как мне задать размер объекта в координатах?

Есть объект и мне надо, чтобы он на сетке был равен по всем сторонам 10. Как это можно задать?

Comment: Попробуйте компонент `LayoutGroup`. Есть три вида: `GridLayouGroup`, `HorizontalLayoutGroup`,  `VerticalLayoutGroup`. Вешается на объект.

Comment: @Methorn как ты узнал, что он про `UI`? o_O

Comment: @Yaroslav решил начать с этой стороны  ̿̿ ̿'̿'\̵͇̿̿\з=( ͠° ͟ʖ ͡°)=ε/̵͇̿̿/'̿̿ ̿ ̿ ̿ ̿ ̿

Comment: @Methorn, Это будет работать для модели?(Это не касается UI)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтин только на UI есть такое. Если вы хотите на вашей модельке задать размеры, то вручную. Или вы хотите редактор изменить?

Comment: @Methorn, просто делаем воксельную игру и для нее внутриигровой редактор. И в редакторе проблема с размерами.

Comment: Попробуйте менять Scale объекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким способом(Вдруг кому пригодится функция):

```
public void ChangeSize(GameObject go, float distance)
{
    try
    {
        Vector3 v = go.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;
        if (v != null)
        {
            v.x = go.transform.localScale.x * distance / v.x;
            v.y = go.transform.localScale.y * distance / v.y;
            v.z = go.transform.localScale.z * distance / v.z;
            print(v);
            go.transform.localScale = v;
        }

    }
    catch (MissingComponentException)
```